# GeoServer REST API layergroups ACL

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

GeoServer UI (http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/) provides the means to configure the security of layergroups by granting read/write access to various roles. I would assume that the UI is simply a front-end on the REST API and that everything which can be achieved through the UI, can also be achieved via REST API directly.

I've tried a GET request on http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/security/acl/layergroups but received an error 404. This is to be expected, for according to the following API references, there is no endpoint for layergroups ACL:

- https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/rest/api/accesscontrol.html
- https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#1.0.0/security.yaml

It would be nice if there were a separate endpoint for layergroups ACL. Apparently, after enabling read/write access of `myrole` to `mylayergroup` via GeoServer UI, the layergroups ACL settings show up in a GET request to the layers ACL:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/security/acl/layers
{'*.*.r': '*', '*.*.w': 'GROUP_ADMIN,ADMIN', 'mylayergroup.r': 'myrole', 'mylayergroup.w': 'myrole'}
```

However, GeoServer seems to expect layers ACL rules in the following format:

```
{'myworkspace.mylayer.r': 'myrole', 'myworkspace.mylayer.w': 'myrole'}
```

I tried a POST request with JSON payload in the same format as the UI seemed to have used, and got an error 422:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/security/acl/layers
JSON: {'mylayergroup.r': 'myrole', 'mylayergroup.w': 'myrole'}


<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Error 422 Invalid rule mylayergroup.r, the expected format is workspace.layer.mode=role1,role2,...</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>HTTP ERROR 422</h2>
    <p>Problem accessing /geoserver/rest/security/acl/layers. Reason:
      <pre>    Invalid rule mylayergroup.r, the expected format is workspace.layer.mode=role1,role2,...
      </pre>
    </p>
    <hr>
      <a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.18.v20190429</a>
    <hr/>
  </body>
</html>
```

How to configure the layergroups ACL via REST API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed it seems impossible to add a rule via the REST API without providing a workspace. The easiest solution would be to assign your Layer Group to a workspace and make the request as suggested in your comment like this:

```
{'myworkspace.mylayergroup.r': 'myrole', 'myworkspace.mylayergroup.w': 'myrole'}
```

If that's not an option for you, you will have to add the rules on a per-layer-basis. Or you can try to prepend a dot right before `mylayergroup.w` and make the request look like this:

```
{'.mylayergroup.r': 'myrole', '.mylayergroup.w': 'myrole'}
```

This request returned a 200 response for me (Geoserver version 2.18) and the rule showed up in the GET request (http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/security/acl/layers.xml), but it's not visible in the GUI and I haven't tested whether or not the rule is actually applied correctly.

Also make sure that your **workspace, layergroup or layer don't contain any dots in their names**, since that will otherwise also give you the above mentioned 422 error response.